# Getting tag list based on date

Tags: wordpress, tags

I know there are lots of options to display tags in wordpress using some functions.

However, I am not sure what the best way is for the following purpose:

I need a list of tags based on the most recently added post.
I simply need the array of the tag list based on the date.

what is the best way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get_tags` with order by term_id, the higher the ID, the newer the tag, so technically that's the sort order you need, just keep the order direction (ie. order=DESC) to ensure you get newest first.

```
$args=array(
    'orderby'=>'term_id',
    'order'=>'DESC',
    'hide_empty'=>false,
    );
 $tags = get_tags($args);

 pr($tags);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to order it by tag that is most recently active? Like if there are tag (A,B,C,D) and if there is a new post under the tag "D", then is there a way to show "D" first as it is most recent?

Comment: To do this we need to execute post loop order by id first and then after we fetch tag respective of post.